# Nikon raw file need to be converted to be open in Photoshop?

Tags: nikon, photoshop, raw

I have to convert to .DNG with an Adobe external tool before use in Photoshop because Photoshop doesn't recognize the Raw file that my Nikon D5000 produce. Is that normal that I have to convert all pictures before processing them in Photoshop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably update your Photoshop or Adobe Camera Raw (not sure it can be updated separately) to [ACR version 5.4 or later](http://postscript.info/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4517), because D5000 was not supported in the previous versions of ACR.

Comment: Yes, you can update a plug-in version without updating Photoshop.

Comment: I'll check your link when coming back at home! Hope it works that would be so sweet!!!

Comment: Sorry to disappoint, but it's not a download link.

Comment: He'll need Photoshop CS4 or better because, as far as I know, ACR is tied to the Photoshop/Bridge versions, so 5.4 is CS4, and 6.1 is CS5. Worth noting anyways.

Comment: I have CS4 and it seem that I need to update my Photoshop to be able too do that.

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop has a Camera Raw plug-in.  You just need to update it to the most recent version.